# Planning to go to Georgia, but I only speak English; will that be a problem?

Tags: georgia-country, language-barrier, georgian-language

I am planning to go to Georgia. I know only the English language. Will I have any language problems with local people? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to TSE, can you please edit the question and include whether you travel alone or with a tour, how long you will stay and whether you are in main cities or all over. That will help us to answer this question, as it is now it is not really answerable in my view.

Comment: You'll be fine. Young people will usually speak some English, as will some people in tourist-facing businesses

Comment: Possible dupe? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/what-language-to-use-in-georgia-the-country-is-english-widely-spoken?rq=1

Comment: If you choose Georgia-Atlanta rather than Georgia-Tbilisi, you can be sure not to have language problems.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wouldn't guarantee that, here in the land of the Southern drawl :-)

Answer (score 10):

I have visited Tbilisi in the past and I only know English and Urdu, I didn’t face any problems with the language but remember that although English is spoken in most major places like hotels, airport etc. it is not spoken in smaller places where there are not many foreigners.

It’s a nice place and people are lovely there and like the comments above say some do speak English. So don’t let the language barrier put you off. Good luck with the trip.

Answer (score 8):

Same as Exit70. But I went to Batumi and I only know English, Thai and Chinese. I didn't have any difficulties at all. I even took buses and local transportation. People might not be able to respond to you fluently in English but at least they will nod for `Yes` and shake head for `No`.

Answer (score 5):

I was in Tbilisi recently and a surprisingly high number of people spoke decent English. Even most staff at ticket booths at metro and train stations knew phrases relevant for their job, which is not normally the case in former Soviet republics.

That said, do try to learn a few Georgian words and phrases; people will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find people speaking English but I wouldn't say it's widespread. From my experience, most guest house administrators, taxi drivers did not speak English, had to communicate in Russian. Some people did not know neither English nor Russian.